# Remove multiple occurrences of a set of strings (array) from the start and end of an input

Tags: c#, html, string, while-loop, substring

Background: Users too often add extra line breaks, which can vary between a BR, P and DIV tags to the end (and sometimes the start) of their input via a WYSIWYG editor. I need to do a clean up to remove any type of line break from the start and end of the input.

Here is an example of input that requires cleaning:

```html
<div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;</div><p>&nbsp;</p><br />this is the input to keep<div>&nbsp;</div><br /><div>&nbsp;</div><p>&nbsp;</p><div>&nbsp;</div>
```

To clean up, I created the following extension, which works well... except, it loops through each line break in order.

```cs
public static string RemoveStartAndEndBreaks( this string input )
    {
        var lineBreaks = new[] { "<br>", "<br/>", "<br />", "<p></p>", "<p> </p>", "<p>&nbsp;</p>", "<div></div>", "<div> </div>", "<div>&nbsp;</div>" };

        foreach( var lb in lineBreaks )
        {
            while( input.StartsWith( lb ) )
            {
                input = input.Substring( lb.Length );
            }

            while( input.EndsWith( lb ) )
            {
                input = input.Substring( 0, input.Length - lb.Length );
            }
        }

        return input;
    }
```

So the issue is, it will only clean all line breaks if they appear in the same order as they are presented in the array. So using the above example, the resulting output is:

```html
<p>&nbsp;</p><br />this is the input to keep<div>&nbsp;</div><br /><div>&nbsp;</div><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Notice it only removes the first break type it finds if it appears at the start or end of the input string - and ignores the rest.

Q1. How do you restart the loop through the array when a match is found?

Q2. Is restarting the loop every time a match is found the only option or is there a more efficient way to check for each occurrence and remove it from the start and the end?

Q3. Have I missed something glaringly obvious?

Please note that the input is html and therefore the resulting output will (potentially) contain the same line breaks described in the string array, which must remain.

i.e. I am only removing the line breaks from the start and end of the input. The ones in the middle need to stay there.

Comment: Can you add an example of what your output should be? Not terribly familiar with html but with that example I should be able to get you a working method.

Comment: Have you tried using the input.replace("<p>", "")

Comment: It's not that simple. I need to remove all line breaks, which can appear in many different formats (as listed in the string array).

Comment: I think, inside of your foreach loop, you can remove both your while loops. And, replace them with input.replace(lb,""); the first param is what you are targeting, and the empty quotes are what you are replacing the target with. In this case nothing.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but the (good) input will contain the same line breaks, which need to remain. I am simply stripping only line breaks from the start and end of the html string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a flag to make sure that there are break lines in Start/End of the input, and loop until the flag is false:

```
    public static string RemoveStartAndEndBreaks(string input)
    {
        var lineBreaks = new[] { "<br>", "<br/>", "<br />", "<p></p>", "<p> </p>", "<p>&nbsp;</p>", "<div></div>", "<div> </div>", "<div>&nbsp;</div>" };

        var isMatched = true;

        while (isMatched)
        {
            foreach (var lb in lineBreaks)
            {
                if (input.StartsWith(lb))
                {
                    input = input.Substring(lb.Length);
                    isMatched = true;
                    break;
                }

                if (input.EndsWith(lb))
                {
                    input = input.Substring(0, input.Length - lb.Length);
                    isMatched = true;
                    break;
                }

                isMatched = false;
            }
        }

        return input;
    }
```

Regard!

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't seem to work. Have you tested it?

Comment: I tested with your example input, and result is "this is the input to keep". What 's case make it fail?

Comment: You're right @Nhan Phan. Your code does work. I adapted it badly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, this will use the array to check each input by cycling through the array rather than the other way.

```
public static string RemoveStartAndEndBreaks(this string input)
{
    var lineBreaks = new[] { "<br>", "<br/>", "<br />", "<p></p>", "<p> </p>", "<p>&nbsp;</p>", "<div></div>", "<div> </div>", "<div>&nbsp;</div>" };

    for (int i = 0; i < lineBreaks.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input == lineBreaks[i])
        {
            //Do This
        }

    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips @xTwisteDx. You made me think about it a bit further.

Comment: I can't see how this would work @xTwisteDx. The input will never be equal to a line break.

Comment: This is showcasing the logic. I'm not familiar with HTML so the best I can do is show the logic. Use an array to test for matches then check through the array and change if there's a match.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the easiest most readable method is to mark a match and use goto to restart the loop:

```cs
public static string RemoveStartAndEndBreaks( this string input )
{
    var lineBreaks = new[] { "<br>", "<br/>", "<br />", "<p></p>", "<p> </p>", "<p>&nbsp;</p>", "<div></div>", "<div> </div>", "<div>&nbsp;</div>" };
    var match = false;

    start:
    foreach( var lb in lineBreaks )
    {
        match = false;

        while( input.StartsWith( lb ) )
        {
            input = input.Substring( lb.Length );
            match = true;
        }

        while( input.EndsWith( lb ) )
        {
            input = input.Substring( 0, input.Length - lb.Length );
            match = true;
        }
        if (match) goto start;
    }

    return input;
}
```

Might not be the most efficient, but it works.

UPDATE: So, using a label and goto is bad practice because it's too primitive and potentially messy. I'm assuming that as a consequence, this answer was down-voted twice. And yet, the answer worked while nobody else provided a working solution. Most of you guys are a lot smarter than I am - that much I do know.

@Nhan Phan provided a smarter, working solution. Well done.

Comment: Oh god no, don't use labels. You're overthinking this.

Comment: Why not? Overthinking?

Comment: What is in the variable `lb`?

Comment: lb = line break

Comment: I'm assuming you have something elsewhere that will feed your `inputs`, whether "clean" or "not clean" correct?

Comment: Sorry @xTwisteDx, I'm not sure what you mean.